# What to look out for when passing a generator into model.fit in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to replace the x and y training data parameters in tf.keras.Model.fit with a generator. However, some subtlety seems to escape me, as the model accuracy doesn't improve with the generator when training.

As far as I understand the documentation, the generator is supposed to yield tuples `(x_vals,y_vals)`, such that `x_vals` is a concatenation of `batch_size`-many training samples along a new 0th dimension, and 'v_vals' is the concatenation of their corresponding labels.

As long as the generator fulfills this, as I understand it, we can just replace the x parameter in tf.keras.Model.fit with the generator and omit the y parameter, though to define an epoch, we also need to specify 'steps_per_epoch' in fit.

There however seems to be something here I misunderstood or forgot, because starting with a model and input data that trains (i.e. its accuracy improves) and replacing the training data array with a generator as discussed, results in a model that doesn't train (i.e. its accuracy instead goes up a little, then however goes back down till its equal to chance).

The corresponding code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 32

#Loading training data:
def load_cifar():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
    assert x_train.shape == (50000, 32, 32, 3)
    assert x_test.shape == (10000, 32, 32, 3)
    assert y_train.shape == (50000, 1)
    assert y_test.shape == (10000, 1)

    #Normalize the data & cast to fp32:
    x_train = np.true_divide(x_train,255,dtype=np.single)
    x_test =  np.true_divide(x_test,255,dtype=np.single)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.single)
    y_test =  y_test.astype(np.single)

    return (x_train,y_train), (x_test,y_test)


(train_x, train_y) , (validation_x, validation_y) = load_cifar()
   


# Defining the generator:
def data_generator_dummy(input_data_x:np.ndarray,
                          input_data_y:np.ndarray,
                          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                          ):
    """
    Given the input_data's, generate infinitely by:
     1. Drawing batch_size-many vectors from input_data_x and input_data_y
     2. Turn the drawn vectors into a mini-batch (with shape  [None]+input_data.shape)

    :param batch_size:
    :param input_data_x, input_data_y: The data on which noise shall be added
    :return: A generator for the input data.
    """
    index =0
    while True:
        # We start with a zero-vector of expected size and fill the drawn samples into it:
        samples_x = np.zeros( [batch_size] + list(input_data_x.shape[1:]),dtype=np.single)
        samples_y = np.zeros( [batch_size] + list(input_data_y.shape[1:]),dtype=np.single)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            samples_x[i] = input_data_x[index%50_000]
            samples_y[i] = input_data_y[index%50_000]
            index +=1

        yield samples_x,samples_y

# Basically a linear classifier:
def make_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,tf.nn.softmax))
    model.build([None] +list(train_x[0,:,:,:].shape))
    return model


#Training:
generator = data_generator_dummy(train_x,train_y,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
model = make_model()
model.summary()
optimizer_adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005/32,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07)
model.compile(optimizer_adam,loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics="accuracy")
model.fit(generator, validation_data=(validation_x,validation_y),epochs=10,
          steps_per_epoch=train_x.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE,
          )

# This one however works:
# model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(validation_x,validation_y),epochs=30,
#           steps_per_epoch=train_x.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE,
#           shuffle=True
#           )
```

---

The model also trains if one first let's the generator generate a long list of samples and then passes those into `fit` as `x`and `y`:

```
#Training:
generator = data_generator_dummy(train_x,train_y,batch_size=50000)
model = make_model()
model.summary()
optimizer_adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005/32,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07)
model.compile(optimizer_adam,loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics="accuracy")
while True:
    samples_x,samples_y = next(generator)
    model.fit(samples_x,samples_y, validation_data=(validation_x,validation_y),epochs=10,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
          )
```

Comment: I think you should in `samples_x` and `samples_y` have multiplication: `samples_x = np.zeros( batch_size * list(input_data_x.shape[1:]),dtype=np.single)` or similar

Comment: @AndrzejO np.zeros takes the target shape of the ndarray. `[batch_size] + list(input_data_x.shape[1:]` means that the first dimension is `batch_size`, followed by whatever were the remaining dimensions of  `input_data_x`. I think that's also what you intended to obtain